# Firefox addon to *easily* remove sections from a web page and remember the removed section

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

Greasemonkey and Stylish both allow a user with some javascript or css knowledge the ability to remove sections of pages. I'm wondering if there's something for more novice users? [Nuke Anything Enhanced](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/951) is a good example that allows the user to right click and select "remove this xxx".  It's great for printing but doesn't remember your selections.  I'm looking for something similar that remembers what's been removed between visits.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Remove It Permanently](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/521)

Comment: Cool.  Thanks reyjavikvi.  That led me to a few other solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Yet Another Remove It Permanently](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7211)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Garrett How useful would you consider screenshots, a description of the tool, and a guide how to use it if its web site becomes unavailable and it's no longer available for download when knowing the program's name? While the answer should include more information, the comment template is not suitable for software recommendations.

Comment: I don't follow what you're getting at, I didn't even make the above comment. It must've been somehow auto-appended as a part of the new review process? If so, that fact needs to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

[Adblock Plus Element Hiding Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4364)